# React Native - iOS - Accessibility 'Bold Text' setting not bolding app text

Tags: ios, react-native

I have a React Native application that would like to support the 'Bold Text' setting for iOS in Settings > Accessibility > Display & Text Size > Bold Text. However, when I enable this, it has no effect on the text in the app. Other accessibility settings such as "Larger Text" do work.

Does React Native not support this setting? Thanks.

Comment: I'm currently looking to make this feature work on my RN app, did you find a way to make it detect the Bold Text setting? Thanks

Comment: Did you find a way?

Comment: @SamuelBeaulieu did you find a way?

Comment: @VAAA gave up after a couple of days. If you find a way please keep us informed!

Comment: @SamuelBeaulieu found a way.